# 2D dynamic programming in F#

Tags: f#, dynamic-programming

I need to implement a simple dynamic programming algorithm in 2D in F#. For simple 1D cases Seq.unfold seems to be the way to go, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7986083/5363

Is there a nice (and efficient) way to achieve a similar result in 2D, e.g. rewrite the following pseudo-code in functional style:

```
  let alpha = 
    let result = Array2D.zeroCreate N T
    for i in 0 .. N-1 do
      result.[0, i] <- (initialPi i) * (b i observations.[0])
    for t in 1 .. T-1 do
      for i in 0 .. N-1 do
        let s = row t-1 result |> Seq.mapi (fun j alpha_t_j -> alpha_t_j * initialA.[i, j]) () |> Seq.sum
        result.[t, i] <- s * (b i observations.[t])
    result
```

assume that all the missing functions and arrays are defined above.

Comment: What's your motivation for rewriting this? Is it just for educational purposes? Looks like the array version above is going to be your best bet for production..

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Actually read code, this is at least functional, does have a slightly different return type, although you could avoid that with a conversion

```
let alpha = 
    let rec build prev idx max = 
        match idx with
        |0 -> 
            let r = (Array.init N (fun i -> (initialPi y) * (b i observations.[0]))
            r:: (build r 1 max)
        |t when t=max -> []
        |_ ->  
             let s = prev |> Seq.mapi (fun j alpha_t_j -> alpha_t_j * initialA.[i, j]) () |> Seq.sum
             let r = Array.init N (fun i -> s * (b i observations.[t]))
         r:: build r (idx+1 max)
    build [] 0 T |> List.toArray
```

Comment: @Grzenio this will return that array - the whole thing is a giant array creation function so I dont need to name it

Comment: I understand, but in the second case of the match you refer to `result`, which is undefined in your version (it used to be the array being created in my imperative version)

Comment: @Grzenio Sorry, missed that, I will try to fix it